# How to handle with Django HTTP.Request, request content-type, query parameters

Tags: python, django, http, content-type

Hi all I'm new in Python and Django actually also in Coding.

I would like to build an app, that can receive a POST-Request with the Content_Type 'application/xml'.

I don't understand how to handle with the HTTP.Request.META in django.
First I would like to check the Content_type, then the Query_string, then Content_Lenght.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import (
HttpResponse, HttpResponseNotAllowed, HttpRequest,)


@csrf_exempt
# Check the HTTP Request Method
def app(request):
    if request.method != "POST":
        return HttpResponseNotAllowed(permitted_methods=('POST',))
    else:
       # checkcontent(request)
    return HttpResponse('OK')

“““
def checkcontent(request):
    if not 'application/xml' in request.meta['CONTENT_TYPE']:
        raise Exception("Invalid content-type. The expected request content-type is 'application/xml'")

“““
```

The Comment Block Doesn't Work!

Can someone explain me?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, [here are all available headers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META) of http request in django

so you need:

```
request.META['CONTENT_TYPE']
```

instead of

```
request.meta['CONTENT_TYPE']
```